# asp.net - Parsing html p content

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, parsing

I want to calculate an operation, so I have a 'p' tag

```
                 HTML

<p id="Kilos" runat="server">5654.64</p>

                c# code

double result = double.Parse(Kilos.InnerText) * 0.621382d;
```

This is not working, How to solve it?

I also tried to parse a value from a hidden field it still doesn't work

```
                 HTML

<input type="hidden" id="Kilos" runat="server" />

                c# code

double result = double.Parse(Kilos.Value) * 0.621382d;
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: @Svek Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: What is the `Kilos` type? Can you provide more information? It looks like you are just randomly assuming it's properties...

Comment: Any value taken from the code is string, I want to convert it to double to make operations on it @Svek

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your c#  (ex: `double result = double.Parse("5654.64") * 0.621382d;`) the problem is your `Kilos` type is not mapping properly to the string you wish to parse. We cannot answer your question without additional information about the `Kilos` type.

Comment: It is an ID, It will always have a numerical value, It need to be parsed that's all I know, I do not know where is the error from @Svek